# Convert String to JasperPrint and Jasper print to String

Tags: java, string, jasper-reports

I am calling a micro-service which will return me a JasperPrint Object  converted to string by toString() method . I am looking for a way to convert that sting to jasperPrint so that I can export the JasperReport from the calling side .

Answer (score 0):

But jasperPrint is serializable, why you dont serialize your object on the server in order to sent it to the client side?